# len function robustness in python and Polymorphism

Tags: python

len method is so robust that it works with many data structures.Following are some of the data structures upon which it works just fine.

```
import numpy as np

list1=[1,2,3,4]
dict1={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
npArray1=np.zeros(4)

print("length of list is:",len(list1))
print("length of list is:",len(dict1))
print("length of list is:",len(npArray1))
('length of list is:', 4)
('length of list is:', 4)
('length of list is:', 4)
```

Then  I found that actually len method calls that data structure's `__len__` method that has all the implementation of how to find length.

```
print("length of list is:",list1.__len__())
print("length of list is:",dict1.__len__())
print("length of list is:",npArray1.__len__())
('length of list is:', 4)
('length of list is:', 4)
('length of list is:', 4)
```

My Question is there some use of Polymorphism being utilized by len function on those data structures?

Comment: Yes, inevitably; the data structures expose the same interface for determining their length (`ILengthable`?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe  a bit more explanation with a small example would be what I need.

Comment: What? You've just listed multiple examples! What *precisely* is still escaping you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better term is "duck typing"; the type of the object passed to `len` doesn't matter, as long as it implements the `__len__` method. Using new-style classes, this could be thought of as a result of polymorphism, since all types are subclasses of `object` (although `object` itself does't define `__len__`, you could pretend that it's an abstract method with no default implementation, but that's stretching this analogy a bit thin). However, `len` would still work with instances of Python 2's old-style class as long as they implemented `__len__` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that polymorphism is being *enabled* rather than *utilized* by the various implementations of `__len__`. Python-style of polymorphism is based on the notion of *interfaces*. Polymorphic code targets the interface. Code that uses `len(x)` will work on any object from a class which provides an implementation of `__len__`.